# firebase messaging EXSPTION

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get token when my app start but I got error

my code is :

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class FirbaseApi{
final _firbasemessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
Future <void> initNotfy() async {
await _firbasemessaging.requestPermission();
final FCMtoken = await _firbasemessaging.getToken();
print('token: $FCMtoken');
//FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) => null)
```

}
}

here the main function:

```
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
//  options: DefaultF
);
await FirbaseApi().initNotfy();
sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnQTi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xY2N.png)

[here the error that I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmLCU.png)

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3898